# How can I ban myself?

Tags: support, ban

I read an answer about [what to do to get self banned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/32306/172011) for a while. The answer was

> Flag one of your posts for moderator attention requesting a self-ban and we will assist.

It did that but my flag was declined as

> Sorry, we're not able to complete your request at this time. But believe me, I understand your concern. :)

Why can't that be done any more?

Comment: Guess that moderators don't have time for games anymore. Seriously - what's the purpose of such thing?

Comment: Time? That'd take like, 5 seconds...

Comment: Just log out and don't log in?

Comment: @slhck and what about 1000 such requests? 5000 seconds are considerable amount of time. Stack Overflow has grown up since '09.

Comment: Your decline reason... Sounds like all the lines were busy, or you didn't press 00 on the automated attendant.  Did you hear a "boop... boop... " sound?

Comment: @Bart That plan is fundamentally unsound. If you've reached this point, your self-control probably won't be enough. You need some outside help.

Comment: @Null I see you are more aware of the background situation than I am. I'll take your word for it.

Comment: 1) Change your associated email to a fake one, or one you don't have access to.  2) Change your password to something you won't remember (just mash the keyboard).

Comment: I fear your only option is to violate the rules. Cleanest way I can think of is creating sock puppet account posting something then have the accounts upvote each other. Automatic scripts will surely detect this, reverse everything and give you some time in the suspension box.

Comment: I would like to suspend my account for a while and not forever since I have to focus the next weeks.

Comment: This is just so sad.  That's it. I'm done and am going outside. I can't take anymore.

Comment: Check out Chrome Nanny: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nanny-for-google-chrome-t/cljcgchbnolheggdgaeclffeagnnmhno Allow yourself 15 minutes a day or so (to get your fix, yknow?) and as long as you don't disable it, the block message should embarrass you enough to get back to work.

Comment: Guys, it's **Thursday.** *You're a day early...*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Browse http://stackapps.com a bit. For example

[Ban myself/enforced break userscript](https://stackapps.com/questions/3251/ban-myself-enforced-break-userscrip)

[No Answering: prevent answering questions](https://stackapps.com/questions/2079/no-answering-prevent-answering-questions)

Answer (score 30):

Banning people as a proxy for self-control sends the wrong message, puts a black mark on the user's account, and is out of scope for a moderator's responsibilities.

It already feels like adult day care sometimes.  Don't institutionalize that perception.

Comment: So what is he supposed to do instead? E-Mail the team?

Comment: Take up another hobby, like running a medical marijuana facility.

Comment: Sounds like a plan.

Comment: Here's how we can create more jobs: Stack Exchange Addict Counselor: If you're addicted to Stack Exchange, we can help, just $100 per month per self-ban and $5 per minute of online counseling. ;)

Comment: *sometimes*? I like your optimism.

Answer (score 6):

Edit your hosts file to point `stackoverflow.com` to `::1`. I'm sure* that'll work.

Comment: Asterisk...with no footnote.  IT BURNS

Comment: * Happy, @John?

Comment: @KeithThompson I've been better, but I suppose that will have to do.

Comment: @John `* = user expresses a reasonable amount of certainty of success if advice is followed. Advice is provided "as is" without warranty of any kind, neither expressed nor implied, including, but not limited to, the success of overcoming a Stack Overflow addiction. User cannot be held liable should success fail to materialize. Terms and conditions apply. Void in P.R. and where prohibited. Statement does not constitute medical advice. Seek advice from a trained professional to help with your addiction. Stack Overflow is a registered trademark of Stack Exchange, Inc., a Delaware corporation.`

Comment: Footnote...with no asterisk. IT BURNS

Answer (score 4):

Instead of going to the extreme of getting yourself banned (which looks bad overall on your account) perhaps there is something you can do client-side (Assuming of course you want to ban yourself for reasons of productivity).

Download a browser plugin like [Leechblock](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/leechblock/) (Firefox) or [Chrome Nanny](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nanny-for-google-chrome-t/cljcgchbnolheggdgaeclffeagnnmhno) (Chrome), it will allow you to maintain a list of sites to block & when to block them. They will allow you to put your browser into 'Lockdown' modes as well, so for an amount of time you specify, you can't even edit the list.

Comment: That's like trying to quit drinking with a fridge full of beer, chained shut and padlocked .. with the key hanging around your neck :P

Comment: I find it helpful because I find that I'll browse to certain sites automatically & without thinking, and I actually have to think to remove a site from the list if it is absolutely necessary that I visit it. Plus as I've said you can put it into Lockdown mode, meaning for all intents and purposes, you've given the key to a small child at the beach and told him to hide it from you, giving him 3 minutes with your eyes closed to hide it.

Comment: On a side note, do you have my beer fridge key? some kid lost it at the beach :P

Comment: I had the same problem, I solved it by gnawing through the chain.