# How to quit meta

Tags: support

Is there a way I can close my meta account?

I have personally didn't find much help here, so I would prefer staying away from here.

Comment: "I would prefer staying away from here" makes it sound more like a dupe of [How can I ban myself?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151885) or [“Ban myself” button in user profiles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32299)

Comment: It makes me quite sad to hear any user say these things... Was there any specific incidents that you feel like sharing? sometimes meta can be a little hostile but overall it's a great place to get feedback on your actions in other main sites... Perhaps we'll be able to change your mind or shed a different light on someone's opinions that were given to you...

Comment: I would guess [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169317/is-the-down-vote-fair) was the final drop.

Comment: I notice also that no one has posted the usual [don't take meta downvotes personally](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences) comment. Down votes on meta usually signify that someone simply disagrees with your opinions and not necessarily that there is something wrong with your posts...

Comment: @Lix It usually happens that when I dare to ask something here, there is the same alliance trying to convince me that asking that question was the worst thing I could do today. Why should I dare to ask anything here if I am always labeled as "not constructive", "sarcastic" or I am even invited to "put my big boy pants on" as it happened one day with a question I deleted.

Comment: Why not just keep away without deleting your account? It's not like you ought to visit and post stuff just because you have account. I understand your frustration, but you do have some valid posts which gave you upvotes and constructive answers; just take some time off Meta but don't lock the door behind you.

Comment: I've never understood this need people have to storm off in a huff. If you don't want to participate in MSO, then *don't*. You don't need to unperson-yourself in some kind of act of Sepukku or something. Just... disappear. It's not something you need to make a big deal over; if you don't want to be here, then don't be here. Having your MSO account deleted only hurts the site.

Comment: @Dan: And the reason your most recent question was downvoted is because it showed that you did absolutely no research on the topic. SO *used to* remove rep for downvoting questions and answers too. They stopped doing that, and the reason for that is outlined here on MSO where it was debated. Had you looked around before asking your question, you wouldn't have needed to ask. So just as someone who asks a question that is easily found with a Google search will be downvoted, so too was yours.

Comment: @Lix: Actually, [I did post that link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169317/is-the-down-vote-fair#comment499572_169317).